# Scrapy: How to extract only html tags from webpages

Tags: html, tree, tags, scrapy

I want to extract only html tag and its text from the webpages.

But there is a condition.

meta, script tags should be excluded.  Anyway tags which are in visible on the page and their parent tags must be scraped keeping their tree structure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most likely do it with simple `xpath`:

```
items = response.xpath("//*[not(self::script)][not(self::meta)]")
for item in items:
    tag_name = item.xpath("name()").extract_first()
    tag_text = item.xpath("text()").extract_first()
    print(tag_name)
    print(tag_text)
```

This will extract all tags and their text.

Comment: @baduk feel free to click accept on the left hand it if has answered your questions!